# Insertion to SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wrote this code:

```
// CurrentFriendsTable
// ---------------------
//| _id | email | uname |
// ---------------------

// FFriend class
class FFriend {
    String email, uname;
    // getter and setter
}

// add single friend to database
public long addFriend(FFriend friend) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CurrentFriendsTable.COLUMN_EMAIL, friend.getEmail());
    values.put(CurrentFriendsTable.COLUMN_UNAME, friend.getName());
    return database.insert(CurrentFriendsTable.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}

// add list of friends to database
public void addListOfFriends(List<FFriend> listOfFriend){
    int lenghOfList = listOfFriend.size();
    for (FFriend friend : listOfFriend)
        addFriend(friend);
}
```

I have two question here:

1. when I add values to table using `database.insert()` function, is that adding the _id automatically ? (I defined the column as _id primary key autoincrement)
2. is the scenario of calling `addFriend(FFriend friend)` function in  `addListOfFriends(List<FFriend> listOfFriend)` good to use of may I change ?

Comment: android internally maintaining one id that is _id

Comment: so dont I have to insert _id manually ?

Comment: ya you can insert manually it depend on you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The primary key is automatically added if you define your key as:

```
primary key autoincrement
```

2) I think it is good. (As suggested [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops) this is a good way for looping)

Just a suggestion: Do not use internal getter and setter in Android. Use it only if you need to get or set the value from outside of your target class ([reference](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#GettersSetters))

Comment: you are welcome @MBH ;) developer Android  is a very good resource for developer

Answer (score 0):

1) It is upto you to do auto increment or you can add primary Key manually. You can do this from the properties of your table in database.

2) In my opinion it is a good way to insert data.